# How can I remove/add the overflow default icon dynamically in the Toolbar component in codenameone

Tags: codenameone

please help me to remove the overflow icon dinamically . I trying to remove using the method

ToolBar.removeAll(); but the overflow icon it don't remove.

Answer (score 0):

You should never mutate the toolbar by adding or removing components from it as it's a special case.

You can only remove the menu button globally using the theme constant `hideLeftSideMenuBool`.

Comment: how can I do that?

Comment: Define a theme constant `hideLeftSideMenuBool` to true but that's global